# When using vertx routes without annotations, how do you define the security?

Tags: rest, vert.x, quarkus

When using vertx routes like the following, how would i use the `@RolesAllowed` and `@Authenticated`?

```
public void routes(@Observes Router router) {
     router.get("/hello").handler(rc -> rc.response().end("Hello from my route"));
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what you're looking for, but you can use interceptor to do some checks https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#intercepting-http-requests

Comment: @DmytroChaban so it's either i rewrite all the routes using `@Route` in order to use the security annotations or use `@RouteFilter`? I was migrating an app with several vertx routes and didn't want to rewrite them. Will see

Comment: Using Vertx directly is quite low-level in Quarkus and the disadvantage is that you will miss a lot of functionality like security (in your case), bean validation, etc.
Maybe you should migrate your code to RestEasy with the use of Mutiny for reactive coding. If you do this, then security (and other stuff) should just work.

Comment: @Serkan can one annotate `@Route` with `@RolesAllowed` and `@Authenticated`?

Comment: @Obby No. That's what I was trying to explain to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, the newest version of Quarkus now has also support for Security within Reactive Routes.

But from version 1.11 Quarkus will come with Reactive JAXRS, which might be better and easier to use than Reactive Routes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have to rewrite my routes to use resteasy with mutiny as shown [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive#reactive-jax-rs-resources). It's an application I'm porting from `vertx` to `quarkus` and I was hoping I wouldn't have to rewrite everything, especially the routes. There is also the case of getting [better performance](https://quarkus.io/blog/io-thread-benchmark/) using reactive routes. In my case, that would be really helpful. But i'll have to write one version with `resteasy` and mutiny and compare